# 'RepeatedScalarFieldContainer' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I want to build a protobuf message on protobuf's API on python.
Here is my proto file. But I can't add "D" in my code.

```
package pkg;
message A
{
    repeated B b = 1;
}
message B
{
    C c = 1;
}
message C
{
    enum D {
        OPTION1 = 1;
        OPTION2 = 2;
    }
    repeated D d = 1;

}
```

Here is my python code.

```
    my_A = A()
    my_B = my_A.b.add()
    my_B.c.add(D.OPTION1)
```

Here is what i got:

**AttributeError: 'RepeatedScalarFieldContainer' object has no attribute 'add'**

Answer (score 8):

I encounter this error and after hours of googling, I found this https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96615/google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedScalarFieldContainer Example 1 shows a `RepeatedScalarFieldContainer` value use `append()`. So try append may work.